# Why won't my app rotate in Xcode 4/iOS5?

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble getting my app to rotate since switching to Xcode 4 and iOS 5. After tearing my hair out, I created a brand-new test project to see if I could get a bare-bones app to rotate.

I created the test project using the 'Empty Application' template. All I added to this template was a UINavigationController, with a UIViewController pushed onto it. There is a nib file for the UIViewController, with one label that says 'Hello'.

On the target Summary screen, I clicked in all the buttons for 'Supported Device Orientations'.

In the .m files for the Navigation and View controller code I changed shouldAutoRotate... to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (YES);
}
```

The test project builds with no issues and runs perfectly. There's a navigation bar and friendly 'Hello' message, but the darn thing won't rotate!

Obviously, I am missing something pretty simple, but I can't figure out what it is. My suspicion has fallen on the .nib. Under 'Simulated Metrics', there is an attribute called Orientation. This is set to Portrait. The only other choice is 'Landscape'. If I change this setting to 'Landscape' the view in the .nib editor changes to landscape, but when I run the app, it runs in Portrait mode, and still refuses to rotate.

Hopefully, someone will get a big laugh out of my blunder and point out the goofy mistake I'm making. Please do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your RootViewController.m find the line

```
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interface Orientation ) );
```

and you can replace this with whatever... like

```
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interface Orientation ) );
```

Comment: I don't actually have such a line in my root view controller, but you put me on the scent of the solution. In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I had been doing:  [self.window addSubview: nav.view], which I guess is a bit old-school. What I needed to do was:  [self.window setRootViewController:nav]. This fixed the rotation problem, although I'm not really sure why. The first way used to work fine for me. I need to read up on this and figure out why it no longer works. Thanks!

Comment: The last view added to the window is the one that receives rotation events; if you were adding another view to the window after nav.view, that could have been why things didn't work for you.

Comment: Was updating an old project and the setRootViewController: thing was the issue. Thanks, John!